# BufferedReader/FileReader is not finding path correctly even with try/catch

Tags: java

I am trying to read from a text file using BufferedReader and FileReader and I am constantly running into this problem:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: dicomTagList.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)C:\temp\workspace\DICOMVALIDATE\dicomTagList.txt
```

I can't seem to find out why this is occurring when I have that file in the correct directory and was able to even verify it with getAbsolutePath() Method in FileReader.

Can anyone advise why this may be?

Here is my code snippet:

```
public void readFromTextFile(File path) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println(dicomList.getAbsolutePath());
        String line;
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dicomList));
        while( (line = bReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
            bReader.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.err.print(e);
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.err.print(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you use `File` instead of the java.nio.file API? This is 2015 and java.nio.file has existed since 2011, that is, Java 7...

Comment: I am using java 6 because the server i will be dropping it on only has Java 6 installed and I dont have sudo access to change that

Comment: You can use a JDK of yours without having to be root, you know...

Comment: That's true but I am afraid that when I convert it to a jar file and attempt to run it on the server, it won't run properly due to it only having JRE 1.6_31

Comment: What happens if you replace dicomList with path?

Comment: Are your permissions set correctly?

Comment: This has NOTHING TO DO. A jar compiled with Java 6 will run on a Java 7 JRE with no problem at all.

Comment: Permissions are set fine and I will try the whole path for dicomList

Comment: @fge, I am saying that I need to have it using Java 6 on there because the server only supports java 6..

Comment: Are you sure that the file really exists? What will the following expression print:

dicomList.exists();

Comment: @ryekayo did you try passing the whole string of file path into FileReader directly without using a variable?

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking, says its false when I print it but that is kind of weird since it can print the AbsolutPath in my code.. Any ideas?

Comment: `File` is "An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames." [Java 7 -- File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html).  That doesn't mean it's guaranteed to exist.  You can use `new File("/path/to/file.txt").createNewFile();` to make a file if you want.  All the `File.getAbsolutePath()` method does is get the absolute form of the path (rather than, for instance, a relative path).

Comment: I cant create the file, i need it to read from the file that already exists

Comment: @ryekayo I was using that as an example of a time you'd want to create a `File` that doesn't yet exist, to help illustrate that it's just an abstraction.

Comment: Let me try it out and see if it does anything.

Comment: @EricHughes that seemed to have worked, you mind putting that in as an answer.. Can you tell why something like that would have worked as opposed to not using the createNewFile() method

Comment: It wasn't intended to answer your question about how to open the file; I still don't know what your directory structure looks like or what it is you did that "worked".  Feel free to answer your own question with what you've found out if you want.

Comment: "the server only supports Java 6" -- what is this nonsense? Have  you at least tried and run a more modern JRE?

Comment: @fge It is my work server, im not planning on doing anything that will get me in trouble even if it is as something as having Java 7 or 8 jre imbedded in the jar file when I create it :)

Comment: Sorry, that's a bad excuse; all that is required to run a new JDK is to download it, unzip somewhere in your $HOME and modify your .bashrc so that the PATH and JAVA_HOME point where appropriate. How hard can it be?

Comment: Its not a matter of it being hard or not. It's just that there is no need to do it. Especially since alot of the libraries I am using are already using Java 6.

Comment: @fge If you were polite and informative rather than condescending and rude; he might be more perceptive to the point you are making.

Comment: @ConfusingCalc yes, my bad; it is just that I am quite infuriated with the fact that even though 4 years have passed, java.nio.file still hasn't caught on in spite of its obvious merits...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that **the file really exists**? What will the following expression print:

```
dicomList.exists();
```

**In Java `java.io.File` is representing just a path to a file, not necessarily a real file.** This means you can create `File` object even if the underlying path does not exist.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: So this advice found the problem, and I still get minus points. Thank you

Comment: I told you man, should have listened. Answers shouldn't be questions. Comment until you know forsure what the problem is, then write an answer. Unless you knew forsure it was the problem already. If that's the case, you shouldn't have answered with a question